# Powershell & XPath to extract string representation of node

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

Is it possible, using XPath, to reconstruct a node's original XML text?

Given this XML in a variable using SelectSingleNode

```
<Rule scope="node" note="Location">
   <Property>location</Property> 
   <Operator>-eq</Operator>
   <Value>Px</Value>
</Rule>
```

I can get the value of attributes and child nodes using `$variable.scope` and `$variable.property`, for example. But when I am validating the XML, for example for valid values of scope, I would like to provide an error log showing the XML exactly as found in the file. So, exactly this in a string

```
<Rule scope="badNode" note="Location">
```

I could reconstruct it, but since the attributes can be in any order, I might not reconstruct it as actually found. So I am hoping there is some mechanism to get the original string without separately reparseing the XML file as a string and searching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could grab the `OuterXml` string representation and just remove everything after the first `>`:

```
$validScopes = 'node','superNode'

$RuleNodes = $xml.SelectNodes('//Rule')

foreach($node in $RuleNodes){
    if($node.GetAttribute('scope') -notin $validScopes){
        $faultyNode = $node.OuterXml -replace '\>.*$','>'
        Write-Error "Faulty node found: $faultyNode"
    }
}
```